# how to force download on one network and upload on another

Tags: networking, server, broadband, bandwidth

lets say that i have an apache server running, and two network cards.
each card is connected to a different network.

C1 is connected to N1, which is an ADSL connection with the port 80 open (so i can reach my server from oustide my lan).
C2 is connected to N2, which is a [very fast] corporate network (no ports open or routes allowed).

how could my server take advantage of C2N2 bandwidth?
would forcing download on one network and upload on another help?

EDIT 1:

what about bonding (seen here: [Two ethernet ports on motherboard. How can I get double the bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32179/two-ethernet-ports-on-motherboard-how-can-i-get-double-the-bandwidth))? would it help?

Answer (score 1):

Well... in a terminal with `curl` you can specify an interface.
From the [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html): `curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/`.

So for a single file you use something like this:

`curl -LO --interface eth1 ftp://ftp.xs4all.nl/pub/test/10mb.bin`

where `eth1` is the interface connected to "C2N2".

Answer (score 1):

It's way more reading than you probably want to do, but you'll probably find [this](http://lartc.org/howto/) useful.  Particularly the sections on source based policy routing (although you would be doing it based on source and/or destination) and split access.  Also, if you did uploads/downloads on a particular port number, that would make it easy to match on.