# Is there a way to distribute Wi-Fi load across multiple adapters?

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, downloads

I have 4 wireless USB adapters, all of which are poorly supported by Linux. The connection is unstable, the USB dongles overheat at regular intervals, and the Wi-Fi adapters themselves often become chokepoints, even with our 6 Mbit DSL.
*(Before you ask: yes, I've updated the drivers, and, yes, they all work like a charm on Windows.)*

What I have to do currently is just use one until it smells funny and can't connect, then unplug it, blow on it, put it in the fridge, and replace it with the next. This can become quite a tedious process during heavy browsing - my computer is on the other side of the house.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to distribute the load across all 4 adapters - so each one never has to process more than ~1.5 Mbps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you need to do is bond the interfaces.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

I just noticed there is a similar question here:

[Two ethernet ports on motherboard. How can I get double the bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32179/two-ethernet-ports-on-motherboard-how-can-i-get-double-the-bandwidth)