# Unable to run 2 ethernet connections at the same time

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, dhcp

I have a workstation with two ethernet ports (eth0, eth1), the problem is that I cannot run with both ports up and running. I can run with either one of them, but not both.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.22.221.29
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.22.221.1
    dns-nameservers 172.22.2.32 4.2.2.2

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 172.22.221.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.22.221.1
    dns-nameservers 172.22.2.32 4.2.2.2
```

Comment: Post the result of `ifconfig` please. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like load balancing you may like to see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding?action=show&redirect=LinkAggregation.

You may also like to have a look at this answer : [Two ethernet ports on motherboard. How can I get double the bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32179/two-ethernet-ports-on-motherboard-how-can-i-get-double-the-bandwidth)