# Ubuntu server 13.04 - network balancing software help

Tags: server, 13.04

I have ubuntu 13.04 server on my media server. Installed for software I have Deluge, Deluge WebUI, Webmin and BlindDNS... what I would like to do is find kind of software that will take and basicly moniter the network trafic so that, say, dearing peak internet usage it limits how much bandwith is being used by an application like say deluge and dearing off peak times (say the whole famly is sleeping) it gives deluge unlimeted bandwith. so the question is dose anyone know of a good program that can do that or maybe even just one that you set by time of day?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network load-balancing with Network Manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17468/network-load-balancing-with-network-manager)

Comment: none of the programs in that question dose what I need it this to do. all the programs in there are for server clusters and dose not do what i am looking for. Let me clearafy what I am looking for. during the day time there is about 2 -3 people on the internet useing 8 mbps of bandwith then the evening hit and we will have 7-8 devices running an internet connection (not including my server) using up to about 13 to 14 mbps then after about 2am hits it drops no one using the internet. right now i have deluge at a set download speed limit of 2000 KiBs (16 mbps) on a 30 mbps totel bandwith...

Comment: so what I am needing is a program that looks at the network and says "hay i've got 3 cliants connected to internet thats using 8 mbps i'm going to limit deluge to 20 mbps" then in the evening it cuts it back even further to 16 mbps then after 2 am it gives deluge the full 30 mbps, I would like for it to be adaptive so that if we all go out to eat that night it let deluge have the 30 mbps untell some one opens a web browser. Thats what I am looking for.

Comment: Please add your more detailed explanation to your question.

Comment: My network has 21 Devices hooked up top to it, 1 Media server (Ubuntu Server 13.04), 6 Desktop PCs, 2 Laptops,  1 Voip phone, 1 Multi-function printer, 6 Cellphones, 3 Tablets, and 1 Smart TV. My Current bandwidth limit is 30 mbps. If I Take and download something that is say 200 Gigs big and let Deluge use the full bandwidth my network craws to a screeching halt until it is done with the download. so my solution was to place a 15 mbps bandwidth limit on it because my media server acts as my networks DNS, Firewall, and Antivirus. I can’t lower the priority of the media server in the router.

Comment: Not everyone in my house is always on the internet so the application that i’m looking would adjust the bandwidth limit of an application based on the bandwidth needs of all the other devices

Answer (score 0):

You could limit or schedule deluge from its menu setting/configuration. In other cases you can use zentyal which comes with bandwidth balancer from its graphical configuration modules. In zentyal it works on a grouped objects. Thus you can group the ip ranges and assign certain bandwidth.

Hope this helps.